# Groovy Space-separated hashmap key

Tags: java, groovy, hashmap

trying to answer a quick question and not having any luck searching online.

I'm learning Groovy and came across this code snippet online:

```
class Person {
    String name
    Person parent
    static belongsTo = [ supervisor: Person ]

    static mappedBy = [ supervisor: "none", parent: "none" ]

    static constraints = { supervisor nullable: true }
}
```

I'm specifically concerned with that last line of the `Person` class body.
What does `{ supervisor nullable: true }` mean? Are those multiple keys that both link to value `true` or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is short for:

```
static constraints = { 
    supervisor([nullable: true])
}
```

Which then means: define a class variable named `constraints` which holds a closure (closures are first class data in groovy).  The closure (when called later) will execute the code within.

The code there is a DSL to configure the constraints for the later data base abstractions. So `supervisor` is a method call (the method does not exist, but the DSL's delegate takes care of that).  [The `()` maybe left out, if "unambiguous"](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/#_optionality).  Next if the method takes a `Map` as param, also the `[]` may be left out.

Note, that `belongsTo` and `mappedBy` are actual maps.